# jQuery selector not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So here is my HTML:

```
<div class="alert alert-info alert-warning" id="rowcounter" style="display: block; bottom: -22px;">
    Are you sure you want to delete 103?
    <div class="btn-toolbar">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-action="deleterow" data-table="contact" data-rowid="103">Yes</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-action="cancel">No</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my jQuery (wrapped in script tags and a document ready function):

```
$('.alert#rowcounter a.btn').on('click',function() {
    console.log('yes');
    if($(this).data('action') == 'cancel') {
        rowCounter('hide');
    }
    if($(this).data('action') == 'deleterow') {
        var tbl = $(this).data('table');
        var targ = $(this).data('rowid');
        $.get('formhandler.php?handle=deleterow&table='+tbl+'&rowid='+targ,function(d) {
            if(d == 'success') {
                $('#rowcounter').removeClass().addClass('alert alert-success').html('Successfully removed '+targ+'!');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

For whatever reason, the jQuery is not selecting the buttons within this toolbar and I'm not sure why. If anyone can help give me a reason as to why this isn't working it'd be appreciated!

Comment: i'm purely guessing, but selecting with a class then id seems weird. Do you get different results by using `#rowcounter.alter a.btn`??

Comment: Is it logging 'yes' in console on click?

Comment: Why are you selecting `.alert#rowcounter`? `#rowcounter` would be satisfactory (and valid).

Comment: I don't know if this would cause your issue, but since IDs need to be unique in HTML, you can get rid of `.alert`, and just use `#rowcounter a.btn`

Comment: @DrewKennedy there are many perfectly valid reasons to use multiple selectors, maybe he has a few blocks like this with different classes.... you don't know anything about the rest of his project.

Comment: Well the `.alert#rowcounter` works just fine by itself, and I know the extra selectors are unnecessary but I've just been trying anything...to no avail. Selecting only the #rowcounter works and makes clicks log but anything deeper than that fails

Comment: Have you done any debugging/logging aside from your `console.log('yes');`?

Comment: Is any of your markup rendered after you've bound this event handler?

Comment: Not sure what you mean @sixfingeredman since it's the click selector thats failing i cant debug anything within it. And the click is a direct descendant to the document.ready, I've been writing jquery for a few yrs but never really found a good way to debug it.

Comment: Write `debugger;` in your script. If developer tools is open, it'll hit it like a breakpoint.

Comment: @DeeMac Do you mean outside the event or inside?

Comment: I mean you're binding this event handler to the buttons. Are those buttons there at the time of doing this? I've seen it many times when markup is rendered (with ajax for example) but the event handler had already been declared prior to the DOM elements existing. I'm guessing this isn't the case, but it's worth ruling it out.

Comment: I made a jsfiddle that shows your selector as working correctly. http://jsfiddle.net/k11tq9rv/1/ Check the console, and you will see that it logs "Yes" when you click the "Yes" link, and "No" when you click the "No" link.

Comment: @DeeMac a debugger right before event and inside were placed, only the first fires. And the html element is inserted through an append call, but it IS before the click event.

Comment: Do you have any other event handlers we cannot see that might be intefering? e.g. do you have `e.stopPropagation()` anywhere? I've tried a fiddle myself, your code works as it is. I'm assuming you have no JS errors with the rest of your code?

Comment: @forgivenson The JSFiddle works perfectly, just not sure why it's different in my code.

Comment: @DeeMac No I do not, and JS is not throwing any errors

Comment: The other possibility (the ONLY other one I can possibly think of) is that your styling is catching you out. Is there an element in the way of what you're clicking perhaps? After that I'm lost for suggestions sorry mate.

Comment: @DeeMac no there isn't, the buttons downclick css fires when I click them and everything works fine...except the actual actions...

Comment: You're at that point in debugging then when I'd strip everything away, and build it all back up slowly until you hit your problem. Starting with javascript, then your markup (classes etc.). Sorry I can't be of any help.

Comment: Yeah, I was at that point and was just hoping maybe I was being stupid somewhere... really appreciate your time though.

Comment: If you can post a more thorough example that recreates the issue, (though not just a huge code dump), then perhaps we can help you identify the cause. But from what you have given us, we are just guessing.

Comment: It is working except that it is throwing up at line `rowCounter('hide');` saying "rowCounter is undefined".

Comment: @SalmanA `rowCounter()` is a faunction I declare in my script. Also, it is commented out due to the fact that I'm debugging so it wouldn't cause any hiccups.

Answer (score 0):

Use #rowcounter a.btn instead of .alert#rowcounter a.btn

```
$('#rowcounter a.btn').on('click',function() {
    console.log('yes');
    if($(this).data('action') == 'cancel') {
        rowCounter('hide');
    }
    if($(this).data('action') == 'deleterow') {
        var tbl = $(this).data('table');
        var targ = $(this).data('rowid');
        $.get('formhandler.php?handle=deleterow&table='+tbl+'&rowid='+targ,function(d) {
            if(d == 'success') {
                $('#rowcounter').removeClass().addClass('alert alert-success').html('Successfully removed '+targ+'!');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You know id is unique indenture so you no need to use class here

Comment: I'm fully aware that IDs are unique and therefore the class in my example is irrelevant. However, it will not make a difference as to whether or not it functions. The same suggestion was made by the person below and I gave him the same answer.

Comment: Well let me clear one thing. Does the div #rowcounter exist from the beginging or you appened after page load

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 $('#rowcounter .btn-toolbar a')
```

Comment: Using any selector deeper than `.alert#rowcounter` does not work.

Comment: Would you create a jsfiddle to simulte the behavior? I guess it would be easier for us to help you on this.